# Search problem in MYSITE

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

Does anybody have idea to fix below problem?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your documents are added recently. In order to search them using search box you have to wait until they gets crawled in your environment.

Check below links for clarification:

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/crawl-site-content
2. [List Search is not working in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215805/list-search-is-not-working-in-sharepoint-online/215819)

Answer (score 0):

Please try/check below things:

1. Re-indexing the all the content at the Search Service Application (Go to SSA > Index Reset under Crawling section) and then run a Full crawl. Then check the results.
2. Delete your content source and recreate this content source. You can refer to below article:

[2013 On premises SharePoint Search Crawl log returns error on The crawler could not communicate with the server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204967/2013-on-premises-sharepoint-search-crawl-log-returns-error-on-the-crawler-could)

3. Disable the LoopBackRequest in registry. To do this, just follow below steps:

   a. Go to command window and type regedit.exe.

   b. Once opened the registry editor, just navigate to:

   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa"

   c. Right click on "Lsa" and create a new 32bit DWORD value.

   d. Rename it as "DisableLoopbackCheck" (Note: you cannot rename it actually. so, once created the DWORD value, directly paste/type as "DisableLoopbackCheck".

   e. Then again modify the value of "DisableLoopbackCheck" as "1".

   f. Close the registry editor. Now start to a full crawl.

If above all do not work, check methods in below article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25863.access-is-denied-verify-that-either-the-default-content-access-account-has-access-to-this-repository-or-add-a-crawl-rule-to-crawl-this-repository.aspx

https://blogit.create.pt/miguelisidoro/2018/08/10/sharepoint-2016-problems-crawling-content-and-the-the-crawler-could-not-communicate-with-the-server-error/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 47 successes (people mysite) and 1 error into the default url : http://sharepoint.domain/, the same error(the crawler could not communicate...), if i search people into search center, it's good and if i search a document, it's not work, have you an idea ?